# Diagnosing a Windows super-hang/freeze 

Tags: windows-7, freeze, diagnostic

Around fall of 2019, I started experiencing a problem whereby Windows would occasional hang/freeze very hard. So hard in fact, that even the ***low-level [crash-on-control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard) function doesn't work!*** That is, pressing the <kbd>Ctrl+ScrollLock,ScrollLock</kbd> hotkey does not trigger a user-generated BSOD and memory-dump (it works otherwise). Moreover, the lock-key LEDs on the wireless keyboard's receiver wouldn't respond to pressing lock-keys even though they usually respond even when the CPU is pegged. Needless to say, when it freezes like this, the mouse cursor doesn't move, and nothing on screen changes anymore, the drive-LED doesn't blink, and there are *no* signs of life in Windows at all.

I thought maybe it had something to do with my hard-drive, but in December, I cloned it to a new SSD and it still happens.

My tinfoil hat keeps whispering that it's a bug that Microsoft introduced in one of the last updates to Windows 7 to force people to switch to Windows 10.

There weren't any hardware changes (it's a laptop) and no software changes that are relevant (drivers, kernel-mode programs, etc.) to the system since before it started doing this. I've been running this system with the Windows installation that came with it since 2012, being very careful what I install on it, and most of the programs I'm using have been here for a long time, long before this problem started (and none of them are things that would have any kind of ability to kill Windows at such a low level that the very-low-level COC function wouldn't work).

Unfortunately, since it's intermittent, it's not practical to try to disable background programs and stuff since it could be a week or two before it happens. Likewise, it wouldn't be practical to use something like ProcessMonitor to log things for a week. And since it completely kills Windows when it happens, it doesn't seem to be possible to get a memory-dump.

I'm not sure even SoftIce could have helped in this situation. I don't even know if Mark Russinovich could help with this.

It's really bugging me (no pun intended) because it can cause data-loss from hanging before a file is saved, but also from hanging right after a file is saved, before the disk cache is flushed—which happened this week. :-\

Has anyone heard of such a problem? Does anyone have any ideas on a way to diagnose it?

Comment: Do you know if when the crash on ctrl scroll works, if the keyboard driver is the PS2 (i8042prt) or the USB one (kbdhid)?  Could you try a plugged in USB keyboard if the laptop is PS2 for example.  Otherwise, you could get another computer setup to kernel debug it over the net interface.  When you have the issue, you could try breaking in live/initiate a dump at that point.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to a a NMI like option to it - http://connecttech.com/product/pci-dump-switch-card/

Comment: @HelpingHand, I've tried both the laptop's internal keyboard (making sure to use the `Fn` key to activate the ScrollLock key correctly), as well as the external USB keyboard. There's no PS/2 ports on it, so I can't use that (and using a PS/2-to-USB adapter would just make it USB).

Comment: @HelpingHand, that's a good question, but unless they come in an mSATA form-factor, it's not going to be an option for a laptop. :-\

Comment: Did you try changing the keys just to be sure the scrolllock key isn’t the issue?

Comment: Ctrl+ScrollLock works (from either keyboard) when Windows is running normally, so it's not that.

Comment: Fair point. In that case I would go with either driver elimination or kernel debug it from another computer over the network. When it hangs you should be good to either live debug it or force a dump.

Comment: @HelpingHand, hmm, I'm dubious that would work, but next time it happens, I'll check the NIC port to see if there's any activity on the LEDs. Do you have a resource on remote debugging the kernel?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection

Comment: It happened yesterday, and the LEDs on the NIC were blinking, but I doubt that had anything to do with the OS, it was probably due to the NIC's own controller, especially since I didn't see any flickering of the HD LED. 

Comment: Did you set up your computer for remote debugging over the network? Bcdedit etc to get a key. Do you have another computer you can run WinDbg on to connect from?

Comment: That's the problem, I need to set up another computer to (try to) do the debugging. I'll see if I can dig out an old system from storage.